# Image got clipped in half

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, imgur

Today I came across a post of a new Stack Overflow user. I realised his image got clipped in half...

Here is an image of the post:

[image]
..

You can find the user profile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021723/shakthivel) and the relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564638/how-to-move-an-image-over-the-canvas-line-or-drawn-line-in-android).

I wanted to know if this is some bug or the user has done something to get that effect. As this is a new user, I don't think he must have done something to get a clipped image. I didn't find any other image getting clipped like this before.

Please take a look at this.

I checked on Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: [There was a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166575/152859) on imgur side that caused some images to get clipped like that, and it was fixed only in April this year. That user you link to joined before it was fixed, if he will re-upload the image it will be fixed for him as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for quick reply...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Haha sweet, I *can* fix it!

Comment: @animuson nice, didn't know mods can do that!