# User profile picture not rendering correctly

Tags: bug, images, rendering

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002167/how-to-project-a-jpa-tuple-result-into-an-entity) question, [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3230038/leo)'s user profile picture does not render correctly for me. It renders like this:

> [image: [appalling-censorship]]

It seems that only the 32px version is rendering incorrectly:

> [image: 16px]
>   [image: 32px]
>   [image: 64px]

This question was also raised in the past, but it was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) although it is now still broken.

Comment: This seems to happen relatively regularly; imgur has messed up generating the reduced size versions. Reuploading the image usually fixes this. Although of course as it's not your user you can't trigger this

Comment: This claims that imgur should have fixed this, which seems not to be the case; [Why is there a peeking duck in my profile pic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic)

Comment: We need that [meta-tag:appalling-censorship] tag again... :P

Comment: The real question is why the 32px version was so much more offensive than the other versions :)