# Why is David's profile image corrupted?

Tags: support, profile-picture

[David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198552/david) has a profile picture of a smiling face:

[image: David's face]

However, in questions or answers, the smaller version of this image shows up with a strange grey corruption at the bottom, blocking the smile:

[image: David's user card]

The image returned for the thumbnail is

[image: David's thumbnail]

Why is this? Is there an error in the thumbnail creation process?*

---

<sub>* If there is a bug, I suppose the problem is with Imgur, but perhaps ye could pass it onto them?</sub>

Comment: Link to corrupted image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mjnmv.jpg?s=32&g=1

Comment: Related: [User profile picture not rendering correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222858), [Why is there a peeking duck in my profile pic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166575) We cannot know how long ago David changed his profile image.

Comment: Should I change the title to "Why is David's smile censored?"

Comment: Most likely he uploaded it before the bug on imgur side was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, images are cropped and resized by imgur.com for use in user-cards. That process can sometimes fail.

Re-uploading the avatar would fix this.

See [Why is there a peeking duck in my profile pic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic)

Comment: So a blocked smile is just a special case of a [peeking duck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166575/147191)?

Comment: @TRiG: ah, yes!