# Why does the image with ID 0JRqu auto download when fetched with the "s" thumbnail suffix?

Tags: support, images, imgur, downloads

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JRqu.png doesn't auto download, and is returned with `Content-Type: image/png`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JRqus.png autodownloads, and is returned with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

Same goes for `1V6MW`, `1YRVj`, `1mT9e`, `2Ad36`, `2eyGW`, `2sZIn` (this one is a gif at original size), `2z7WW`, `3KPFC`, `3gRfJ`.

For the record, the reason I find this noteworthy is because the vast majority of images hosted on i.stack.imgur.com return the same `Content-Type` for both their original and small thumbnail images. Some return different types (usually JPEG), but this smaller subset of those is even weirder.

... Why?

Comment: What does "auto download" means?

Comment: Appending ‘s’ changes the size. I assume imgur just renders the image and streams it instead of saving a copy. [There are more postfixes than ‘s’ btw](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3318/9161)

Comment: No clue why it does, but can confirm the odd behaviour. 0JRqu.png just appears in the browser, 0JRqus.png insists on downloading.

Comment: @ColleenV [I know](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs). that's why I used the right-ish word "thumbnail suffix"

Comment: @ColleenV I fail to see why it couldn't render it on the fly and send it as `image/jpeg` or `image/png`, or whatever the image format of the original image is.

Comment: I'd say it's just a rare bug on imgur side when they create the thumbnail version, same root cause as the [peeking duck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic). So sometimes the image is just ruined, sometimes it cause the server to set wrong content type to it. I'm afraid only imgur developers can confirm or fix that.

Comment: how is this question not about the software that powers the stack exchange sites?

Comment: About being off topic I can see the reasoning: the bug is on imgur side, SE can't do anything to fix it. But it's in the gray zone for being on topic here, as it's a third party service SE is using (soon to be "used") so in theory SE can approach imgur and ask them about it.